# Drawing a rectangle with SDL2

Tags: c, sdl-2

I just started using SDL2 and I already have a problem.
I want to create a window and paint it in red.
But it remains white, and I don't understand why.

Here is the code :

```
int main (int argc, char** argv) {
    SDL_Window* pWindow = NULL;
    pWindow = SDL_CreateWindow("Jeu de la vie", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
        640,
        480,
        SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);

    SDL_Surface* pSurface = NULL;
    pSurface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(pWindow);
    SDL_FillRect(pSurface, NULL, SDL_MapRGB(pSurface->format, 255, 0, 0));

    while(1);

    SDL_FreeSurface(pSurface);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(pWindow);
    SDL_Quit();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 85, accepted):

There are several issues with your code, I'll try to address most of them.

### Initialize SDL

`SDL` and `SDL2` needs to be initialized before you can use it. The way to initialize SDL is the following function.

```
int SDL_Init(Uint32 flags)
```

Where `flags` can be a different value for different subsystems. Use `SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING`, to initialize everything.

```
int SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING)
```

Read more about it [here.](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_Init?highlight=%28%5CbCategoryAPI%5Cb%29%7C%28SDLFunctionTemplate%29).

---

### Initialize `SDL_Window` and `SDL_Renderer`

`SDL_Renderer` and `SDL_Window` needs to be set up before you can use them. You already create your window properly, so I won't cover that. Here's how to set up an `SDL_Renderer`

```
SDL_Renderer* SDL_CreateRenderer(SDL_Window* window,
                                 int         index,
                                 Uint32      flags)
```

`index` defines what driver to use. Set it to `-1` to use the first driver that supports the other arguments. 
`flags` are used to make the rendering optimized, software rendiring, prevent vsync, etc.. Set it to `SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED`.

Read more about `SDL_CreateRenderer` [here](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_CreateRenderer?highlight=%28%5CbCategoryAPI%5Cb%29%7C%28SDLFunctionTemplate%29).

### Mixing `SDL` and `SDL2`

`SDL_Surface` is primarily something used in `SDL`, not `SDL2`. `SDL2_image`, `SDL2_ttf` etc still used `SDL_Surface`, but they are converted into an `SDL_Texture` before they can be used.

`SDL_FillRect(...);` is also mostly a `SDL` thing. But as stated above, the `SDL_Surface` can be used, but you need to convert it to an `SDL_Texture` first :

```
SDL_Texture* SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(SDL_Renderer* renderer,
                                          SDL_Surface*  surface)
```

Read more [here](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface?highlight=%28%5CbCategoryAPI%5Cb%29%7C%28SDLFunctionTemplate%29).

And use

```
int SDL_RenderCopy(SDL_Renderer*   renderer,
                   SDL_Texture*    texture,
                   const SDL_Rect* srcrect,
                   const SDL_Rect* dstrect)
```

To render it, read more [here](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RenderCopy?highlight=%28%5CbCategoryAPI%5Cb%29%7C%28SDLFunctionTemplate%29).

### Infinite loop ( `while(1);` )

You REALLY shouldn't do this, it'll just loop forever. Use `SDL_Delay( 5000 );` to pause for 5000msec or 5 seconds.

### A simpler way

You can use

```
int SDL_RenderDrawRect(SDL_Renderer*   renderer,
                       const SDL_Rect* rect)
```

To draw a rect.

You should use

```
int SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(SDL_Renderer* renderer,
                           Uint8         r,
                           Uint8         g,
                           Uint8         b,
                           Uint8         a)
```

To set the color of what you are drawing, use

```
int SDL_RenderClear(SDL_Renderer* renderer)
```

After which you call your `SDL_RenderDrawRect()`

Up until this point, everything has been drawn "behind the scenes." To render it to the screen, use

```
void SDL_RenderPresent(SDL_Renderer* renderer)
```

### Example

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
    SDL_Window* window = NULL;
    window = SDL_CreateWindow
    (
        "Jeu de la vie", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
        640,
        480,
        SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN
    );

    // Setup renderer
    SDL_Renderer* renderer = NULL;
    renderer =  SDL_CreateRenderer( window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);

    // Set render color to red ( background will be rendered in this color )
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor( renderer, 255, 0, 0, 255 );

    // Clear winow
    SDL_RenderClear( renderer );

    // Creat a rect at pos ( 50, 50 ) that's 50 pixels wide and 50 pixels high.
    SDL_Rect r;
    r.x = 50;
    r.y = 50;
    r.w = 50;
    r.h = 50;

    // Set render color to blue ( rect will be rendered in this color )
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor( renderer, 0, 0, 255, 255 );

    // Render rect
    SDL_RenderFillRect( renderer, &r );

    // Render the rect to the screen
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);

    // Wait for 5 sec
    SDL_Delay( 5000 );

    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

### Result

[image: Rendered result]

---

You can read more about SDL2 on my [blog.](http://headerphile.com)

Comment: A few fixes... SDL_Renderer requires an argument and the SDL_RenderDrawRect requires to pass in the address of R

SDL_RenderClear(pRenderer);
..
SDL_RenderDrawRect(pRenderer, &r);

Comment: @Begui Thank you! I must have written the example code too quickly as I had the arguments correct in the first part.

Comment: Very good explanation!  But I'm encountering one problem maybe you can help with.  When I try to setup the renderer by calling SDL_CreateRender, NULL is returned and when I call SDL_GetError(), it tells me "OpenGL context already created".  What does this mean?  Nothing appears to render, and I'm guessing it's because of that.  I tried making my file the exact same as yours and it still happens.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: @JulianCleary I have updated the code, there was a few errors in it. If you still can't get it to work, you should create a new question with your code. I'll be happy to help you further.

Comment: The `SDL_CreateRenderer()` `index` is the rendering driver, not the `SDL_Window`. Best left as `-1` for this example. (To initialize the first one supporting the requested flags.)